# Java app open new Layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two Layouts in my App the first screen ConnectActivity and the the second screen ControllerActivity. I need an object from ConnectAvtivity in ControllerActivity. How can I give this  object to ControllerActivity. The object is c from typ Connection. Connection is another class.

```
Connection c = new Connection();
```

I start the class with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ControllerActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); //STRG + SHIFT + NUMPAD
```

How I can give c to this class?

The head of ControllerActivity:

```
class ControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Can I do ControllerActivity in ConnectActivity (class in class)?

Comment: You give instances of classes (or other variables) to the Intent objects

Comment: Incance of class